# Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core, cors

Net core app and react JavaScript. I am doing some proof of concepts for authentication. I have cloned some sample app from github and developed .net core API and trying to call the API. I have the following code to call API in my react app.

This is fetch.js

```
export const callApiWithToken = async(accessToken, apiEndpoint) => {
    debugger;
    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
    const options = {
        method: "GET",
        headers: headers
    };

    return fetch(apiEndpoint, options)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Below is Hello.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { MsalAuthenticationTemplate, useMsal, useAccount } from "@azure/msal-react";
import { InteractionRequiredAuthError, InteractionType } from "@azure/msal-browser";

import { loginRequest, protectedResources } from "../authConfig";
import { callApiWithToken } from "../fetch";
import { HelloData } from "../components/DataDisplay";

const HelloContent = () => {
   
    const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal();
    const account = useAccount(accounts[0] || {});
    const [helloData, setHelloData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (account && inProgress === "none" && !helloData) {
            instance.acquireTokenSilent({
                scopes: protectedResources.apiHello.scopes,
                account: account
            }).then((response) => {
                callApiWithToken(response.accessToken, protectedResources.apiHello.endpoint)
                    .then(response => setHelloData(response));
            }).catch((error) => {
                // in case if silent token acquisition fails, fallback to an interactive method
                if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
                    if (account && inProgress === "none") {
                        instance.acquireTokenPopup({
                            scopes: protectedResources.apiHello.scopes,
                        }).then((response) => {
                            callApiWithToken(response.accessToken, protectedResources.apiHello.endpoint)
                                .then(response => setHelloData(response));
                        }).catch(error => console.log(error));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }, [account, inProgress, instance]);
  
    return (
        <>
            { helloData ? <HelloData helloData={helloData} /> : null }
        </>
    );
};
export const Hello = () => {
    const authRequest = {
        ...loginRequest
    };

    return (
        <MsalAuthenticationTemplate 
            interactionType={InteractionType.Redirect} 
            authenticationRequest={authRequest}
        >
            <HelloContent />
        </MsalAuthenticationTemplate>
      )
};
```

Then I have configured CORS in my .Net core app. Below code is in ConfigureServices method.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000");
                                  });
            });
```

Below code in Configure method

```
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseAuthentication();
```

My react app is running at https://localhost:3000 and API app at https://localhost:44367/weatherforecast

When I run the APP I see below error

```
Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44367/weatherforecast' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I added CORS in .Net core but still I get the error. Can someone help me to understand the issue and fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `Authorization` header in your Cors configuration. The following options can be used:

```
options.AddPolicy("MyAllowHeadersPolicy",
    builder =>
    {
        // requires using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000")
               .WithHeaders(HeaderNames.Authorization);
    });
```

or:

```
options.AddPolicy("MyAllowAllHeadersPolicy",
    builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000")
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: thanks marteendev I have added below code services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(
                    "CorsPolicy",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                        .WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000")
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                    });
            }); but dint work out